# How do I set default values on properties in composite components in NativeScript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm writing a composite component in NativeScript, for which I am extending a GridLayout.  I have the properties (mostly) working, but I need to set default values for them.

If I set the values in the constructor, attempts to set values to those properties in CSS will fail: the "setNative" function will not get called for the CSS values—only for the setting of the value in the constructor.

I'm also using the "getDefault" function on the property to attempt to set a default value.  The function does not get called.

composite-component.ts

```
@CSSType("CompositeComponent")
export class CompositeComponent extends GridLayout {

    constructor() {
        super();

        // If I set this here, none of the attempts to set it in CSS will work
        // this.height = 50;

        let innerComponent = builder.load(__dirname + '/composite-component.xml') as View;
        innerComponent.bindingContext = this;

        this.addChild(innerComponent);

    }

    [heightProperty.getDefault](): PercentLength {
        return 50;
    }

    [heightProperty.setNative](value: PercentLength) {
        // For some reason, it is necessary to call this from here, otherwise the CSS won't work at all...
        this.notifyPropertyChange("height", value);
    }


}
```

home.component.html

```
<StackLayout verticalAlignment="center">

    <CompositeComponent image="res://icons/icn_person/icn_person"></CompositeComponent>

</StackLayout>
```

home.component.scss

```
CompositeComponent {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

I would expect the "heightProperty.getDefault" to be called to assess the default value, but it isn't.  The default value remains "auto" which is not at all what I want it to be by default.

Comment: You need not to trigger property change (`notifyPropertyChange`), it's fired by default for every properties. `height` changes can be monitored by adding a `heightChange` listener but if you are using {N} Core flavor you may have to add this listener after the loaded event, that's a known limitation. Regarding the default value, it's not called as the height property is handled differently. Its registered on [Style](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/styling/style-properties.ts#L195) class, not on the View or it's descendants.

Comment: When I delete "this.notifyPropertyChange("height", value);" the component is updated for height values in the CSS.  I agree that it's weird, but it's their because of trial and error.  All i'm trying to do is get the height property from the css.  I know it's registered to the Style class.  I just want to know how to set a default height for my component.

Comment: I think you can use the `setNative` callback, return your default value if it's auto which is actual default measurement.

Comment: But if it's a CSS property, then my component can't access it as one of its own properties.  How do I access the `setNative` callback then?